# Show that if 2 is a primitive root mod a prime p then $p \equiv 3$ or $p \equiv 5 \pmod 8 $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So far I have that $(\frac{2}{p}) = (-1)^{\frac{p^2-1}{8}} = -1 $ so $\frac{p^2-1}{8}$ must be odd but I am not sure where to go from here?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

(1) A quadratic residue modulo $\;p\;$  cannot be a  primitive root modulo $\;p\;$ ;

(2) $\;2\pmod p\;$ is a quadratic residue iff $\;p=\pm1\pmod 8\;$

Comment: I'm still not really following. Am I just allowed to assume (2)?

Comment: I've no idea, @user123049. The hints are there: either you've already studied them and thus you can assume or else you'll need to prove them.

Answer (score 0):

If the material already proved lets you conclude that $\frac{p^2-1}{8}$ must be odd, then you are almost finished.

For if $p$ is odd and not congruent to $3$ or $5$ modulo $8$, then $p\equiv \pm 1\pmod{8}$. We show that in those two cases $\frac{p^2-1}{8}$ is even.

We do the argument for $p\equiv 1\pmod{8}$. If that is the case, then $p$ is of the shape $8k+1$. It follows that $\frac{p^2-1}{8}=8k^2 +2k$, and $8k^2+2k$ is even.

A very similar argument takes care of $p\equiv -1\pmod{8}$.